# Message bus over ZeroMQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, ipc, zeromq, dbus

I'm going to implement a distributed message bus over ZeroMQ and I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible. My requirements are:

- multiple processes are connected to a bus, some of them are on the same machine, some not.
- processes can subscribe to some topics
- unfortunately, no multicast (it is not supported in the production environment - Amazon)
- I need multilanguage soultion (at least for C++, Haskell and Python)

Approaches I'm considering are:

### 1. Directory Service + Mesh topology

- there is a single Directory Service which has a list of all connected processes and their addresses.
- each process connects to DS on start and asks for addresses of others
- each process has a Pub and Sub sockets connected to all other processes (mesh topology)

### 2. Broker

- all processes are connected to a broker which distributes messages using Pub socket.

Are there any other/better architectures to use with ZeroMQ to create such message bus?

Comment: Have a look into Vert.x (http://vertx.io/) 
It can help you to implement a service bus.

Comment: There's a bridge for ZMQ and Vert.x at https://github.com/p14n/vert-zeromq

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately your solution is for Java but I need it multilanguage (some components are in C++, some in Haskell and some in Python). I updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to have a look to [nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org), which has a built-in BUS topology and some
other interesting ones like SURVEY. It is a library by Martin Sustrik the original zmq
author.

You can find some discussion about BUS on Martin Sustrik blog: http://250bpm.com/blog:17